# Convert tabular data to graphviz DOT format

Tags: graphviz

I have tabular data with the following fields constituting a record:

- SourceID
- SourceLabel
- SourceGroupID
- TargetID
- TargetLabel
- TargetGroupID

I would like to convert this data to graphviz DOT format either programmatically or as part of a script. In particular, I would like to cluster nodes according to their GroupID.

This seems like it would be a common task--are there existing tools / code (preferably Python or R) examples that do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the [NetworkX library](https://networkx.github.io/) for Python might do what you want. What you need to do is read in an edge list (see [networkx.readwrite.edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite/edgelist.html)), process it to create the groups or anything else you need, and write out the Graphvis dot file (see [networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot.html)).

NetworkX can do other graph visualizations on its own without Graphvis ([gallery](http://networkx.lanl.gov/gallery.html), [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html)), and can export [many other formats](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite/index.html) including GraphML. There are tons of open source tools to visualize graphs that can import GraphML, like
[NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/), a great introductory tool that integrates network analysis into Excel 2007/2010 (*Disclaimer: I'm an advisor for it*). Other awesome tools include [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) and [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/), while [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/) and [UCINet](http://www.analytictech.com/ucinet/) are some proprietary alternatives.